# Drag and drop builder

Tags: webforms

This [site](https://demo.webform.com/form/add) comes with a nice drag and drop [builder](https://webform.com/features/drag-and-drop-builder) for [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform). What modules are required to create a builder like this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking to find, recommend, or suggest hosting providers, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main module to accomplish this is the [Form Builder](http://drupal.org/project/form_builder) module, which integrates with Webform.  Acquia also uses a similar-but-different module for Drupal Gardens.